# Regex Get all concordances

Tags: java, regex, match

I need take all strings which contains this text
%variables% some text here %/variables%

Example

```
%enca% something here %variables% take this text %/variables% 
other stuffs here, I dont need this 
%variables% I need this too %/variables%
other stuffs, etc
```

What I have is this:

I try with this:
%variables%(.*?)%/variables%

And works like this (only one match)

http://regexr.com?34cge

but in Java does not work :

```
private boolean variablesTag(String s)
    {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/%variables%(.*?)%/variables%/gs");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
     //do some stuff...stored, work with the string, etc...
    };

    return true;
}
```

What I really appreciate it if you can show me the way to take the string inside.
What I want is this:

take this text
this too

I'm using NetBeans...

**SOLUTION**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%variables%(.*?)%/variables%",Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Without flags does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you don't need the "/" delimiters on the regex, in fact it is incorrect to use them. If you want to add flags to the regular expression, there is a two-argument version of `Pattern.compile` (see the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)).

Change

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/%variables%(.*?)%/variables%/gs");
```

to, for example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%variables%(.*?)%/variables%", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Then access the captured stuff with `matcher.group(1)` inside the loop.

Comment: +1 correct. Regarding the slashes, it's not so much that "you don't need them", it's that they have nothing whatsoever to do with regex - they are an application language syntax construct.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this pattern:-

```
Pattern.compile("%variables%(.*?)%/variables%");
```

And then get the values required like this. Choose whichever you wish.

```
while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group()); //Prints this "%variables% take this text %/variables%"
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //Prints this " take this text"
}
```

Comment: Without flags does not work, I think is because the text contains carriage return, anyway, thanks alot for your time, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String input = "%enca% something here %variables% take this text %/variables% "
            + "other stuffs here, I dont need this"
            + "%variables% I need this too %/variables%"
            + "other stuffs, etc";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%variables%(.*?)%/variables%");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.format("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

Output

```
 take this text 
 I need this too
```

Comment: Without flags does not work, I think is because the text contains carriage return, anyway, thanks alot for your time, I appreciate it

Comment: Crashman, There are no CRs in "String input". Did you try to copy my sample as is? I guess you did but.. it should work..

Comment: I just tried to add both "\r\n" and "\n" after each  [+ "] - works too.

Comment: You are totally right, you code works, but I really don't know why doesn't not work with my text, here's again = "%inicio%
%encabezado%
%variables%
%float,var1,10%
%/variables%
%variables%
%int,var1,10%
%/variables%
%/encabezado%
%/inicio%"  this text comes from jTextArea